# Which pH should I aim for when neutralizing restored/refinished antique surfaces?

Tags: paint, plaster, finishing, chemicals, wood-finishing

I have recently used different chemicals to restore, refinish and treat various types of wall and millwork surfaces.  E.g. I have stripped old paint using [Peel Away 1](http://www.dumondchemicals.com/pro-peel-away-1.html) from plaster and antique millwork, which I believe is basic and needs to be neutralized with acid (vinegar or similar).  I also cleaned mortar and dust residues from exposed brick using [hydrochloric acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid), which I neutralized with a baking soda solution (basic).  In yet another example, I plastered some brick walls with a homemade plaster mix ([hydraulic lime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_lime) + sand), which also is basic.

After completing all of these surface treatments, should I always aim to achieve a pH of 7 by neutralizing with a solution of the opposite pH?  Or are there other factors to be taken into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

If you are cleaning something that can be washed, you can neutralize the pH with water.  After using HCl on bricks, I would just hose them off.  The acid will become very dilute quickly.  pH just measures the concentration of hydrogen ions in a solution, so if you add a bunch of water (neutral pH) the pH will approach neutral.

I also don't think you need to worry about the pH of solids such as dried plaster.

Comment: i couldn't hose it off, it was indoor.  so i sponged it with baking sode in water